# map all requests instead of specific pattern in Spring Boot

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have VueJS Single Page Application inside the Spring Boot aplication and I want to make vue-router to handle all of the requests instead of these ones which url starts with the `/rest/**`.

So i wrote regular expression `^(?!/rest/).*` to match everything that doesn't start with the `/rest/` and I try to make the request mapping like this:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{path:^(?!/rest/).*}")
    public String forwardRequests() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have rest controller file:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/project")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Project getProjectById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return projectService.getProjectById(id);
    }
}
```

which returns JSON with project details. I've got some pages like `/login` and `/projekty` so I need to forward them to `index.html` to handle routing with vue. I know I can do something like this:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/login", "/projekty"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forwardRequests() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

and it works great, but I don't want to explicitly specify every urls, that's why I try to use regular expression. And I think I use wrong the `path` variable, but I dont know how.

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ section `Using "Natural" Routes`

Comment: Works like charm ! You made my day, was searching for the OAuth case for hours

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, as @JDB said, the `AntPathMatcher` compares the paths and finds the best match. So you don't have to be worry about the endpoints, which have specified paths, like my `/rest` api.

You can add this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
  return "forward:/";
}
```

and all of your requests, eg. `/login`, will be forwarded correctly to `index.html`, where javascript can handle it.

The problem is with the URLs like `/project/edit/33`. They doesn't match this regular expression, so you will see the `Whitelabel Error Page 404 Not Found`. You can write this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
  return "forward:/";
}
```

and it works fine, but if you have security enabled, the `/ouath/token` will return:

```
{  
   "timestamp":"2018-02-05T09:13:28.104+0000",
   "status":405,
   "error":"Method Not Allowed",
   "exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
   "message":"Request method 'POST' not supported",
   "path":"/oauth/token"
}
```

so you have to exclude oauth urls:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{path:[^\\.]*}", "/**/{path:^(?!oauth).*}/{path:[^\\.]*}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String forward() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

and it works fine.

If you have problems with other endpointes provided by the framework, like `/health` you can change regular expression to `/**/{path:^(?!oauth|health).*}/{path:[^\\.]*}`

It looks awfull, but it works. I belive someone will post here a better and cleaner solution.

Comment: I cant understand why the "^(?!oauth|health).*" is allowed when using the var storing like "{path: }", but it does not work out of it, spring does not understand caret, nor .*

Answer (score 2):

I don't know spring specifically, so I'm just making my best guess based on experience with other frameworks.

First, shouldn't the pattern exclude the forward slash, since you are already including it in your path?

```
/{path:^(?!rest/).*}
```

If that doesn't work, then all I can think is that the AntPathMatcher doesn't support lookaheads.

The typical pattern for this design would be to implement both the `/rest/*` and `/*` routes. In some frameworks this is just about ordering them correctly. According to [Spring MVC's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison), you may need to play around with the rules to make the `/rest/*` route "more specific".

Here are the rules:

> When multiple patterns match a URL, they must be compared to find the best match. This done via AntPathMatcher.getPatternComparator(String path) which looks for patterns that more specific.
>
> A pattern is less specific if it has a lower count of URI variables and single wildcards counted as 1 and double wildcards counted as 2. Given an equal score, the longer pattern is chosen. Given the same score and length, the pattern with more URI variables than wildcards is chosen.
>
> The default mapping pattern /** is excluded from scoring and always sorted last. Also prefix patterns such as /public/** are considered less specific than other pattern that don’t have double wildcards.
>
> For the full details see AntPatternComparator in AntPathMatcher and also keep mind that the PathMatcher implementation used can be customized. See Path Matching in the configuration section.

So, based on my interpretation of those rules and your code, I think something along these lines would work:

```
// Your more specific patterns will take precedence
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/**")
    public String handleRestRequests() {
        // forward this to your rest services
    }
}

// Your less specific patterns will only apply if the more specific ones don't match
@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public String forwardRequests() {
        // Everything else
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: The forward slash in regex is a good point, but it still doesn't work. I edited my question to show you how I handle the REST request. I have many @RestController files and I don't know to set an order, priority or forward to rest endpoints.

Comment: @kojot if you read those rules, then it sounds like you can use `/**`. Spring will automatically decide that it's the least specific rule and will only apply it if no other rules match. Try it and see.

Comment: Every time I tried to use `/*` or `/**` I go into the endless loop.

Comment: That makes sense actually, since you are forwarding to /. Maybe rather than forwarding, you should actually create a view/controller. That's about the limit of what I can suggest.

Comment: How would you handle WebSocket? It gets overridden by the forward on my end.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a default handler method

```
  @RequestMapping()
  String defaultHandler() { 
    return "This is a default method";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a second look... your string is `/{path:^(?!/rest/).*}`.

There is a first `/`, then the regex also declare a first `/`. This regex will match `/rest/*` because it verifies `/(?!/rest/).*` and not `(?!/rest/).*`.

**Old answer and wrong, see @JDB comment**

The `/` character is a special character in regexes and needs to be escaped.

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:^(?!\\/rest\\/).*}")
    public String forwardRequests() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

Since `\` is also an escaping character for strings in Java, you need 2 of them.

Comment: @kojot - `/` is [not typically a special character in regexes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) (though it is a special character in **javascript**, since it's used to denote a regex).

Comment: @JDB My bad, the real error was indeed the double slash at the beginning of the path as said in your updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the request path matching is usually cumbersome for cases we want to exclude. We can handle this specific case of WebHistory redirection with a ResourceResolver.

My case was :

```
/admin/index.html => backoffice vuejs entry-point
/admin/css/**     => backoffice css files
/admin/js/**      => backoffice js files
/admin/**         => backoffice routes
/**               => API endpoints
```

The backoffice static files were served by SpringBoot as static resources under `/admin`.
I needed to serve `/admin/**` resources which were not static resources but webapp routes as the `index.html`.
For that use case I've implemented a simple `ResourceResolver`.

```java
public class WebHistoryPathResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

    private final PathResourceResolver pathResourceResolver = new PathResourceResolver();
    private final String fallbackPath;

    public WebHistoryPathResourceResolver(String fallbackPath) {
        this.fallbackPath = fallbackPath;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        Resource resource = pathResourceResolver.resolveResource(request, requestPath, locations, chain);
        if (resource == null) {
            return pathResourceResolver.resolveResource(request, fallbackPath, locations, chain);
        }

        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain
    ) {
        return pathResourceResolver.resolveUrlPath(resourcePath, locations, chain);
    }
}
```

And then instantiating the handler like that :

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer adminWebMvcConfigurer() {
    final String prefix = "/admin";

    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry
                .addResourceHandler(prefix + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:" + prefix + "/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new WebHistoryPathResourceResolver("index.html"));
        }

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController(prefix)
                .setViewName(prefix + "/index.html");
        }
    };
}
```